# How to get link url from content that i publish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i'm using native php & mysql, creating content using tinymce.
how to get the link url from each post that i'm publish?
for example my base link is localhost/web
i have a content with title tes link url is localhost/web/tes
[image: Here content i publish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a router class + pretty URL or a framework...
For native php start with structure such as switch case and match url within case. Either way you need to understand how to handle properly a request / response. What comes from client (usually a browser) is the request and what gets out of the http server is a response. Read about HTTP protocol very very important! Look at the request and response structure in order to understand how you can build yours. Look at the PHP `$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays for request data... for a secure application you've to filter input and escape output. There are plenty of info about this topic. Also take in consideration sql injection! I'm sorry but your question is a simple hard one!

Start to read a LOT

So: You can put a `<a>link</a>`tag like this: `<a href="<?php echo($link) ?>">link</a>` on your buttons!